Proof check for Cauchy's Theorem for finite abelian group
I want to know if this proof contains any error.

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$. If $p$ is a prime with $p \mid n$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.

Attempted proof.
Since $G$ is finite abelian, $G=\langle x_1, \cdots, x_k\rangle=\langle x_1\rangle_G + \cdots + \langle x_k\rangle_G$ for finitely many non-identity elements, where every $\langle x_i\rangle_G$ denotes the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $x_i$, and there is a surjective homomorphism of abelian groups $f: \langle x_1\rangle_G \oplus \cdots \oplus \langle x_k\rangle_G \to G$, where the direct sum is external. Thus, $n \mid \prod_{i=1}^k \text{ord}(x_i)$. This implies, for every prime $p \mid n$, $p$ divides at least one of $\text{ord}(x_i)$'s. $\square$
I've only seen a proof using induction, and it's not very intuitive. I want to check if it is an issue when $\langle x_i\rangle_G \cap \langle x_j\rangle_G\neq \{e\}$ for some $i\neq j$. Thanks in advance.

I find induction on the order quite intuitive and simple. For a course in group theory or abstract algebra, one should apply a Sylow theorem to obtain Cauchy's theorem in general. Anyway, see here for a discussion.

You are using $n$ twice for two different things.

@Randall Thanks for pointing that out. Just updated.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Bill, the OP has mentioned the precise step where they are unsure.

The proof is almost fine. I think you should complete it by adding in the end why it is sufficient that $p$ divides the order of some $x_i$. Essentially, you are using Cauchy's Theorem for cyclic groups - but yeah that's easy.

Please do not answer off-topic SV questions.

It's not an off topic question, please double check.

It is off-topic because they don't say why they doubt it.  The goal is to have these be mathematical questions, so that the answers add  (global) value to the site (vs. only the asker). Such extremely local Q&A's only serve to obfuscate search results (the primary purpose of the site is to be an easily searchable library - not a proof checking machine)
